# Onedrive SDK VB.NET - Access to One Drive using User Refresh Token from AAD

Tags: vb.net, azure, onedrive

I need an app to set up OneDrive to stay logged in so after much researching and testing I have arrived at the following code. 
I Use Microsoft Graph to get the correct user refresh token from Azure but it seems the way I am trying to create the OneDriveClient object is not right.

Everything works up to the point of accessing the OneDrive drive.

The Stack Trace shows that the token is assigned successfully however i get the following error...

```
Exception thrown: 'Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException' in mscorlib.dll
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory Information: 2 : 8/03/2017 1:33:22 AM: 6f67595b-... - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
Access Token Hash: 6nRavv....
Refresh Token Hash: jGnzim1W6Cw...
Expiration Time: 8/03/2017 2:33:21 AM +00:00
User Hash: null

CFSOneDriveSync.vshost.exe Information: 0 : 8/03/2017 1:33:22 AM: 6f67595b-... - AcquireTokenHandlerBase: === Token Acquisition finished successfully. An access token was retuned:
Access Token Hash: 6nRavv....
Refresh Token Hash: jGnzim1W6Cw...
Expiration Time: 8/03/2017 2:33:21 AM +00:00
User Hash: null
```

Here is the code...

```
Imports Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk
Imports Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.Authentication
Imports Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory.GraphClient
Imports Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory

Shared siteprefix As String = "/sites/dev"
Shared clientId As String = "dr44f435-...."
Shared clientSecret As String = "aQhnY6nJlqqaQXjU/UyQ...."
Shared odc As OneDriveClient
Shared myDrv As Drive
Shared TokenForApplication As String

Public Const AadReturnUrl As String = "urn:....0:oob"
Public Const AadTargetUrl As String = "https://domain.onmicrosoft.com"

Private Shared Async Function Connect() As Task

    Const authString As String = "https://login.windows.net/0a6154a1-...."

    Const resAzureGraphAPI As String = "https://graph.windows.net"

    Const serviceRootURL As String = "https://graph.windows.net/0a6154a1-...."

    Dim serviceRoot As New Uri(serviceRootURL)

    Dim adClient As New ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot, Async Function() Await GetAppTokenAsync())

    Dim authContext As AuthenticationContext = New AuthenticationContext(authString, False)

    Dim userCred As UserCredential = New UserCredential("user@domain.com.au", "**************")

    Dim authResult As AuthenticationResult = Await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resAzureGraphAPI, clientId, userCred)

    TokenForApplication = authResult.RefreshToken

    Dim adalAuthProvider As AdalAuthenticationProvider = New AdalAuthenticationProvider(clientId, AadReturnUrl, authContext)

    odc = New OneDriveClient(AadTargetUrl + siteprefix + "/_api/v2.0", adalAuthProvider)

    Dim authTask As Task = adalAuthProvider.AuthenticateUserWithRefreshTokenAsync(TokenForApplication)

    myDrv = Await odc.Drive.Request.GetAsync          <-- ERROR RAISED HERE

End Sub

Private Shared Async Function GetAppTokenAsync() As Task(Of String)

    Dim authenticationContext As New AuthenticationContext(authString, False)

    Dim clientCred As New ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret)

    Dim authenticationResult As AuthenticationResult = Await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resAzureGraphAPI, clientCred)

    Return authenticationResult.AccessToken

End Function
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Greg J